In PyCharm/IntelliJ, I have to set the run config to "Current File" every time I create a new file. It doesn't take it automatically
In PyCharm/IntelliJ, every time I create a new file, I have to set the run configuration in the top right to "Current File". Observe the pic below after creating a new file:

Observe the file name to the left of green run button. Current file is Temp.java but in the run config, it is still ThisAndSuper.java. I have also run my code and you can see the output is not "In main" as expected, but coming from ThisAndSuper.java file.
I have set my run to keyboard shortcut to Ctrl+Q. I understand that once we run it using Ctrl+Shift+F10, it automatically takes the current file and starts working from the second time. But is it possible to configure it in such a way that every time we create a new file it automatically takes the current file to run instead of us having to set it each time?

There's no main method yet.  Doesn't a green execution arrow show up when you add the main method?  no need to set it every time.  just make the class executable with a main.

Is there a workaround if I don't want to add the main method everytime either?

No.  Just do it.  No idea what you expect to happen without the main.

I am sure it's not the issue of the main(). I just checked, whether I have main or not, unless I first run it with Ctrl+Shift+F10, it won't happen

what is executed if not main?

I added some more code in the main method and tried. Let me update the image.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Why don't you just use play button in editor?

NO, thank you.  No chat for me.
